# Accessing a USB device through Windows application

Tags: windows, usb

I want to access a mobile phone connected through a USB port through a simple Windows Application. Is there any tutorial such as http://www.robbayer.com/files/serial-win.pdf (for serial port) which can help me understand the basics of USB port programming in C/C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to check out [Jan Axelson website](http://janaxelson.com/usbc.htm)  Lots of good info, as well as the book USB Complete.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/